# jQuery Returns true but doesnt enter if correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When I alert

```
$(this).attr("clicked") == "aa"
```

it alerts `true`. But this code does not alert aa.

```
 if ($(this).attr("clicked") == "aa"){
  alert("aa");
 }
```

Can anyone help with this issue?
Thanks

**EDIT**

Content of this is

```
<a id='Comedy' hoverb='green' clicked='aa'>want to laugh</a>
```

Whole piece of the code:

```
$('.left a').live("click", function() {


 if ($(this).attr("clicked") == "aa"){

  $(this).css('background',black);
  alert("aa");

 }

  else {

 //do somethingelse

}

});
```

Comment: Can you show us the context of `$(this)`?

Comment: The "left" class is not in the a tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

clicked is not a default attribue .. Try this instead..

Also **this** does not make any sense without a context .. If you do not specify the context this means the window..

```
<a id='Comedy' hoverb='green' data-clicked='aa'>want to laugh</a>

$('#Comedy').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).data("clicked") == "aa") {
        alert("aa");
    }
});​
```

// try this

```
$('#Comedy').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr("clicked") == "aa") {
        alert("aa");
    }
});​
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
$(this).css('background','black');   <---- black needs to be bound in '' ..Missing that
```

[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MQ6ky/1/)

[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MQ6ky/2/)

Comment: You might also want to use === instead of == (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: I put the clicked attribute manually. So it can be anything but the point is it doesnt enter if correctly even if returns true..

Comment: UH! The only reason was that syntax error! I guess I need some rest:) Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is in this block

```
$(this).css('background',black);
```

put the property value as

```
$(this).css('background','black');
```